# Create a list from data frame with length(list) same as nrow(df)

Tags: r

Here is a small example data frame:

```
> dput(head(cluster_socrata_csv))
structure(list(Cluster = structure(c(1L, 13L, 24L, 35L, 46L, 
57L), .Label = c("cluster1", "cluster10", "cluster100", "cluster11", 
"cluster12", "cluster13", "cluster14", "cluster15", "cluster16", 
"cluster17", "cluster18", "cluster19", "cluster2", "cluster20", 
"cluster21", "cluster22", "cluster23", "cluster24", "cluster25", 
"cluster26", "cluster27", "cluster28", "cluster29", "cluster3", 
"cluster30", "cluster31", "cluster32", "cluster33", "cluster34", 
"cluster35", "cluster36", "cluster37", "cluster38", "cluster39", 
"cluster4", "cluster40", "cluster41", "cluster42", "cluster43", 
"cluster44", "cluster45", "cluster46", "cluster47", "cluster48", 
"cluster49", "cluster5", "cluster50", "cluster51", "cluster52", 
"cluster53", "cluster54", "cluster55", "cluster56", "cluster57", 
"cluster58", "cluster59", "cluster6", "cluster60", "cluster61", 
"cluster62", "cluster63", "cluster64", "cluster65", "cluster66", 
"cluster67", "cluster68", "cluster69", "cluster7", "cluster70", 
"cluster71", "cluster72", "cluster73", "cluster74", "cluster75", 
"cluster76", "cluster77", "cluster78", "cluster79", "cluster8", 
"cluster80", "cluster81", "cluster82", "cluster83", "cluster84", 
"cluster85", "cluster86", "cluster87", "cluster88", "cluster89", 
"cluster9", "cluster90", "cluster91", "cluster92", "cluster93", 
"cluster94", "cluster95", "cluster96", "cluster97", "cluster98", 
"cluster99"), class = "factor"), Socrata = structure(c(17L, 17L, 
1L, 13L, 14L, 16L), .Label = c("Assault", "Assault with Deadly Weapon", 
"Breaking and Entering", "Community Policing", "Death", "Disorder", 
"Drugs ", "Missing Person", "Other", "Other Sexual Offense", 
"Property Crime", "Property Crime Residental", "Robbery", "Theft", 
"Theft from Vehicle", "Theft of Vehicle", "Traffic", "Unknown", 
"Vehicle Recovery", "Weapons Offense"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Cluster", 
"Socrata"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which looks like this:

```
> head(cluster_socrata_csv)
   Cluster          Socrata
1 cluster1          Traffic
2 cluster2          Traffic
3 cluster3          Assault
4 cluster4          Robbery
5 cluster5            Theft
6 cluster6 Theft of Vehicle
```

I would like to create a list where cluster is the key and Socrata is the value.

I tried simply nesting inside a as.list() function but this returned a list with 2 values, one for the clusters and one for values.

In this instance I would like a list with 6 items in it where the first item key is cluster1 and it's value is Traffic. For the 6th item it's key would be cluster6 and it's value "Theft of vehicle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
setNames(as.list(df$Socrata),df$Cluster)

setNames(as.list(as.character(df$Socrata)),df$Cluster) # not to return levels
```

Comment: Thanks that also works but it's returning all the levels, is there a way to prevent that (see comment below in zweps answer)

Answer (score 1):

I would think something as simple like this...

```
B = as.list(A$Socrata)
names(B) = A$Cluster
```

where A is your dataframe

If you want to have only a subset of the levels, you can try

```
B = as.list(droplevels(A$Socrata))
```

This will give only the levels that are actually present. If you don't want any levels, then we have to remove the factor class from A$Socrata by:

```
B = as.list(as.character(A$Socrata))
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work except all the levels are being pulled in to. Anyway to prevent that? ```> cluster_socrata_lut[1]
$cluster1
[1] Traffic
20 Levels: Assault Assault with Deadly Weapon Breaking and Entering Community Policing ... Weapons Offense```

Comment: @DougFir see my edits, they will probably help you!
EDIT: Ah.. I see you have another accepted answer. So you can ignore my edit!

Comment: Thanks all the same!